# Confused of the result of printf("(%d,a=%d,a+b=%d)",a=a+3,a,a+b);

Tags: c, printf

Given the following code:

```
int a=0,b=2;
printf("(%d,a=%d,a+b=%d)",a=a+3,a,a+b);
```

why the result is `(3,a=3,a+b=5)`

Comment: for another example:
int arr[] = { 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
 int *ptr = arr;
 *ptr += 3;
 printf("(%d,%d,%d)", *ptr, *ptr++, *(ptr++));
the result is (8,7,9)

Comment: @The Paramagnetic Croissant, haccks
I don't think this question is duplicate

Comment: @Martin James
I saw this code from a book or an article maybe, and confused about this bad code, I will never create those codes by myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are printing the result of an assignment (`a=a+3`) which is the assigned value (`3`).
But the evaluation order of the parameters depends on the compiler (undefined behaviour). it could print:

```
(3,a=3,a+b=5)
```

or:

```
(3,a=0,a+b=2)
```

or even:

```
(3,a=0,a+b=5)
```